# Xcode 6 stopped cleaning project before building

Tags: c++, xcode, git, build, project

I have a strange issue on my Xcode 6. Today I worked at home and when finished a part of C++ code, I committed it on my personal git remote server.

Okay then I came to work, successfully checked it out and then built it. The first build was as usual, it took a few minutes to compile, but other one I made after correcting a code, simply have been done in a few milliseconds, like Xcode took a previously built version and use it this time.

And that was it! I notice I've got the previous functionality, like I use the first version of code, which I checked out after start my work computer.

So the question is - how to force Xcode 6 automatically clean the previous builds before compiling?

P.S. I also noticed that breakpoints changed their color from blue to gray. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Looks like the matter in file's owner permissions. Trying to do `sudo chown -R boss:staff /Users/boss/Codes/` made the issue gone.